# Meteor Compensate for Asynchronousity

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor

I'm trying to make a method in Meteor which reads a file and outputs the result. Below is my code.

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({

retTemplate: function(templateName){

    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    var ret;
    fs.readFile("./../../../../../client/" + templateName + ".html",{encoding: 'utf8'}, function(err, data) {

    if(err)
        return "ERROR";

    console.log(data);

    return data;
    }); 

  }
});
```

Client:

```
    Meteor.call('retTemplate', submitName, Meteor.user(), function(e, r){
      console.log(r);
      $('#editTempData').val(r);
    });
```

The code on the server side works (the server-side console is updated with the content of the html file), but the method is returning undefined to the client. I believe this is due to Meteor's asynchronous functions. Is there a way around this? I've been fiddling around for a bit to no avail.

Thanks.

EDIT: I think it would work if there weren't a readFile method called, because that sets up a bit of a double-asynchronous call, which might be the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to use Futures.

Working server:

```
Meteor.methods({

retTemplate: function(templateName){


    var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var fut = new Future();
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    var ret;
    fs.readFile("./../../../../../client/" + templateName + ".html",{encoding: 'utf8'}, function(err, data) {

    if(err)
        return "ERROR";

    console.log(data);
    fut['return'](data);

    }); 
    return fut.wait();


  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a value from an asynchronous method and then return it to the client like that. Here is an alternative (but not ideal) solution.

Create a `new Meteor.Collection` on the client/server and simply subscribe subscribe/publish this collection. Save the data returned from `fs.readFile()` into your collection, and your client will be automagically notified when this occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I fiddled around and found a future class in Node.js which solved it too.